# Permanently disabling touchscreen from Windows in a cross-operating system way

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, touchscreen

I have a laptop that came with Windows 8.1. The touchscreen was broken, and now randomly taps on one side of the screen; as this takes over the cursor, the laptop becomes unusable when the touchscreen is enabled.

I disabled the touchscreen from the Device Manager and all was well. However, when I wanted to install Ubuntu, the Ubuntu installer doesn't recognize the fact that I disabled the touchscreen from Windows. (As the random tapping coincidentally occurs over the area where the language selection options are for the Ubuntu installer, I found myself with a Bengali install, which I later removed.)

So, how can I disable the touchscreen from Windows in a way that all operating systems will recognize?

I've tried deleting the touchscreen entry entirely from Device Manager, but Windows scans for and re-adds the touchscreen at startup, making that not an option.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to globally disable your touchscreen without physically unplugging it inside the laptop. This is because Ubuntu and Windows 8 handle devices and drivers separately.

To disable it when you go to install Ubuntu, you will need to make [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/a/486919/237790) change to the LiveCD.

To make this change, you will need to use Ubuntu (or any other Linux distribution). You will need to extract the `.squashfs` file from `\casper\filesystem.squashfs` inside your Ubuntu LiveCD.

You will need to have `squashfs-tools` installed, and then follow the instructions [HERE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80305/mounting-a-squashfs-filesystem-in-read-write) to unpack the `.squashfs` file. Then make the change above, and repack it using those instructions.

You will need to replace this new `filesystem.squashfs` with the one currently on your install media (the one your LiveCD/USB) in the same location `\casper\filesystem.squashfs`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! And what if I'm installing Ubuntu with WUBI from a USB drive?